a sheaf whose stalk at every point is finitely generated is of finite type?
Let $(X,O_X)$ be a ringed space, and an $O_X$ module sheaf $F$ is of finite type if for every point $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an exact sequence of $O_X|_U$-modules of the form $O_X^n|_U\rightarrow  F|_U\rightarrow 0$.
Question: if an $O_X$ module $F$ has stalk $F_x$ finitely generated $O_{x,X}$ module at every point $x$, can we deduce that $F$ is of finite type? I believe this is not true, can anyone provide a counterexample for this? Any idea on this is very welcome!

It is worth noting that this is true when $X$ is finite, or more generally when every point has a finite open neighborhood (this has finitely many stalks, choose their generators, choose sections representing them, shrink the sets down, and take the union of the generators).
There are counterexamples among quasi-coherent sheaves on affine schemes. In other words, there is an $R$-module $M$ such that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ the localization $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is finitely generated over $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, but $M$ itself is not finitely generated.
This happens already for $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Let $(k_p)$ be any sequence of positive integers indexed by prime numbers. Consider the abelian group $M = \bigoplus_p (\mathbb{Z}/p)^{k_p}$. This is torsion, so the localization at the zero ideal is zero.  The localization at a non-zero prime ideal $(p)$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{k_p}$ which is finite. Clearly, $M$ is not finitely generated.
